# Wrong type argument: listp, eval-after-load in .dir-locals.el

Tags: emacs, eval-after-load

I'm writing my first `.dir-locals.el`, and I'm getting an error in `*Messages*`.

Code:

```
(eval-after-load "grep"
  '(add-to-list 'grep-find-ignored-directories "blur"))
```

Trace:

```
.dir-locals error: Wrong type argument: listp, eval-after-load
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The general format for `.dir-locals.el` is described here:

- <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(emacs) Directory Variables` <kbd>RET</kbd>
- http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Directory-Variables.html
- http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DirectoryVariables

To evaluate code, you must use the special pseudo variable name `eval`, as described at:

- <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(emacs) Specifying File Variables` <kbd>RET</kbd>
- http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Specifying-File-Variables.html
- http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/LocalVariables

e.g.:

```
((nil . ((indent-tabs-mode . t)
         (eval . (eval-after-load "grep"
                   '(add-to-list 'grep-find-ignored-directories "blur")))
         (fill-column . 80)))
 (c-mode . ((c-file-style . "BSD")
            (subdirs . nil))))
```

*However*, `grep-find-ignored-directories` is not an automatic buffer-local variable, and we are not explicitly setting it as a directory local variable here (the 'local variable' in question here is `eval`), so when `grep-find-ignored-directories` gets set this way it is set globally, which is surely not what you intended<sup>1</sup>.

You might try something like this:

```
((nil . ((eval . (eval-after-load "grep"
                   '(add-to-list 
                     (make-local-variable 'grep-find-ignored-directories) 
                     "blur"))))))
```

but in fact that's still wrong, as once you have visited a file under this directory, that `eval-after-load` (which is a global setting) will be triggered as soon as `grep` is loaded, no matter *which* buffer you are in at the time, so you could easily add your "blur" value locally in some unwanted buffer from which you called grep, while also *failing* to add it for any of the previously-visited buffers in which you wanted it.

The simplest solution is probably to forcibly require grep before setting the variable:

```
((nil . ((eval . (progn
                   (require 'grep)
                   (add-to-list 
                    (make-local-variable 'grep-find-ignored-directories)
                    "blur"))))))
```

That ensures that all files under the directory will get the local value (and that files elsewhere will not).

Now, that's one approach to the general problem, but taking a look at this specific case, and <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>v</kbd> `grep-find-ignored-directories`, this variable provide some functionality which can make the solution simpler, and not require grep to be loaded unnecessarily.

Your .dir-locals.el file can set a local variable thus:

```
((nil . ((my-ignore-blur-p . t))))
```

And in your .emacs you can do the following:

```el
(defun my-ignore-blur-p (dir)
  "Return non-nil when the `my-ignore-blur-p' local variable is set."
  (local-variable-if-set-p 'my-ignore-blur-p))

(eval-after-load "grep"
  '(add-to-list 'grep-find-ignored-directories
                (cons 'my-ignore-blur-p "blur")))
```

Then when you execute `rgrep` from any buffer in which this local variable is set, the custom function we have specified in the global `grep-find-ignored-directories` variable will return a non-`nil` value, which will cause "blur" to be included in the list of ignored directories.

(n.b. I used the same name for both the function and the variable because I can -- elisp has separate name spaces for variables and functions -- but that's not necessary. For clarity, I'm referring to the *function* in the `eval-after-load` code, and the *variable* in the function code and the .dir-locals.el file).

Or you could just base the behaviour of the `my-ignore-blur-p` function on the `dir` argument (being the directory being searched), and ignore local variables altogether. That would make the decision to include or omit "blur" from the list completely independent of the buffer from which you initiated the rgrep command, which might be even more desirable.

---

<sup>1</sup> If adding "blur" to `grep-find-ignored-directories` globally *is* what you wanted, then don't use `.dir-locals.el` at all -- just add your `eval-after-load` call to your .emacs file.

Answer (score -1):

There is a specific format for the `.dir-locals.el` file. You need to associate a certain mode with certain variables. If you want to apply the variables for all the modes use `nil`. The following works:

```
((nil
  (eval-after-load "grep" '(add-to-list 'grep-find-ignored-directories "blur"))))
```

However this might not be (probably is not) what you want. If you were to load `grep` before editing any file in this directory this would not have any effect.

Comment: That's all kinds of wrong, I'm afraid. Firstly you are setting a local variable with the symbol `eval-after-load`. Secondly if it did actually do what you thought, it absolutely *would* be evaluated for files visited after loading grep, because if the library is loaded then the `eval-after-load` body is evaluated right away. (You're correct about it not being what you want to do, mind; just not for the right reasons.)

Comment: Makes perfect sense. Explains why the only autocompletion I got was for eval and not eval-after-load. Thanks for the corrections.