# How to add include path to flycheck c/c++-clang?

Tags: c++, emacs, flycheck

I tried to add include path to `flycheck` c/c++-clang, but it didn't work.

I put `foo.h` in `~/local/include` and added the following lines to `init.el`:

```
(add-hook 'c++-mode-hook
          (lambda () (setq flycheck-clang-standard-library "libc++")))
(add-hook 'c++-mode-hook
          (lambda () (setq flycheck-clang-language-standard "c++1y")))
(add-hook 'c++-mode-hook
          (lambda () (setq flycheck-clang-include-path
                           (list "$HOME/local/include/"))))
```

And in a file called `test.cpp` I wrote

```
#include <foo.h>
```

`flycheck` said that

> 'foo.h' file not found

What am I doing wrong? I'm using `emacs24`, `flycheck.el` from `package.el` and `clang3.4`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use `expand-file-name` and `~` to refer to paths in your home directory:

```
(add-hook 'c++-mode-hook
          (lambda () (setq flycheck-clang-include-path
                           (list (expand-file-name "~/local/include/")))))
```

Flycheck does not use the system shell to run Clang, nor does it otherwise attempt to expand shell parameters in command lines.  Hence, `$HOME` is passed **literally** to Clang, which does obviously not work.

Comment: Is there any way to do that sort of configuration on a per-project basis?

Comment: @Magnus Emacs offers Directory Variables for this purpose.  See the manual for more information.

Comment: Yes, that's an option of course, but it's rather limited; only variable values are allowed, and `flycheck-clang-include-path` treats realitve paths relative to the file being checked, which means that more complicate organizations of code are hard to support.

Comment: @Magnus You can use `eval` to run arbitrary code from directory variables, and you can use absolute paths to avoid issues with relative paths.  Beyond that, Flycheck has no particular support for “per-project” settings, and won't have any time soon, since there's no concept of “project” in Emacs.

Comment: Thanks, that gave me enough info to find this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16237506/wrong-type-argument-listp-eval-after-load-in-dir-locals-el

Comment: @Magnus can you share what you figured out? I have a source tree that builds a couple node modules and I'd like an easy-ish way to drop a directory local file in two places to get the include paths right

Answer (score 11):

I do not want to get credit by this answer but it could be useful to someone.
Using the accepted answer and comments to set **flycheck variable** with **Directory variables**:

You have a project with the C++ source code in `~/myproject`.
Add the file `~/myproject/.dir-locals.el` with the following content:

```
((nil . ((eval . (setq flycheck-clang-include-path
                       (list (expand-file-name "~/myproject/include/")))))))
```

That worked for me.

Comment: See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44357963/161979) for a (slightly) more involved example.