# Setting flycheck-clang-include-path in .dir-locals using projectile

Tags: emacs, elisp, projectile, flycheck

Trying to set flycheck-clang-include-path without the need to include the full path of the project include directories using projectile, but I get errors... So this works:

```
((nil . (
     (company-clang-arguments . (
                     "/home/user/Downloads/project/headers"
                     "/home/user/Downloads/project/source/mon"
                     ))
         (flycheck-clang-include-path . (
                     "/home/user/Downloads/project/headers"
                     "/home/user/Downloads/project/source/mon"
                     ))
     )))
```

But this does not:

```
((nil . (
     (company-clang-arguments . (
                     (concat "-I" (projectile-project-root) "headers")
                     (concat "-I" (projectile-project-root) "source/mon")
                     ))
         (flycheck-clang-include-path . (
                     (concat (projectile-project-root) "headers")
                     (concat (projectile-project-root) "source/mon")
                     ))
     )))
```

The error that is reported:

```
flycheck-substitute-argument: Value ((concat (projectile-project-root) "headers")) of flycheck-clang-include-path for option "-I" is not a list of strings
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possibility is using an `eval` to evaluate the quoted forms in your `dir-locals`.  This may be considered unsafe since anything could be evaluated in such a form.

```
((nil 
  (eval . (let ((root (projectile-project-root)))
            (setq-local company-clang-arguments
                        (list (concat "-I" root "headers")
                              (concat "-I" root "source/mon")))
            (setq-local flycheck-clang-include-path
                        (list (concat root "headers")
                              (concat root "source/mon")))))))
```

Comment: Thanks. I get this error: File local-variables error: (void-function projectile-project-root)

Comment: @SFbay007 make sure you have enabled `projectile-mode`.  Or autoload that function in your init since it isn;t autoloaded from projectile.

Comment: could you please advice on how to do that in code? I am new to lisp.

Comment: I moved projectile initialization in the init file all the way to the top and now it works...Thanks.

Comment: @SFbay007 if you want to autoload a function you can do it via `(autoload 'projectile-project-root "projectile")` assuming that `projectile.el` is on your `load-path`

Comment: jenesaisquoi, it is suggested to use (locate-dominating-file) in place of projectile like in https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/12940/variable-project-root-folder-in-dir-locals-el how to apply that in your code?

Comment: you can replace `projectile-project-root` above with whatever you want to use.  If you have a new question you should start a new thread to get more exposure

Comment: I did replace projectile-project-root with (locate-dominating-file default-directory ".dir-locals.el") but that did not work.